# Slow API Request Loop in Python

Tags: python, json, api, request

I am trying to make some simple API requests from IEX's cloud server to grab closing prices for a number of securities. I am successfully pulling the data, but it is taking forever and its not even a lot of data. It would be a HUGE help if anyone would be able to help me restructure my code to make it faster and more efficient. Below is what I have thus far.. Thanks so much guys

```
for i, row in Universe.iterrows():
    try:
        request = urllib.request.urlopen('https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/'+Universe['ticker'][i]+'/chart/date/'+Px_1+'?chartByDay=true&token=TOKEN').read()
        data = json.loads(request)
        Universe['Px_1'][i] = data[0]['close']
    except:
        Universe['Px_1'][i] = np.nan
```

Comment: Are you sure that restructuring the code will make it faster? did you use a profiler to confirm the bottleneck is your code and not the server you send requests to?

Comment: I am not sure what would be a good speed? I ran a test and it came in at 156 ms.Which was for one ping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `requests` package to create a reusable persistent connection, that should make each request faster:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

for i, row in Universe.iterrows():
    try:
        data = session.get(url).json()
        Universe['Px_1'][i] = data[0]['close']
    except:
        Universe['Px_1'][i] = np.nan
```

You can also run the requests in parallel using a thread pool:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool


def get_px1(ticker):
    url = 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/' + ticker + '/chart/date/' + Px_1 + '?chartByDay=true&token=TOKEN'
    try:
        data = session.get(url).json()
        return data[0]['close']
    except:
        return np.nan


Universe['Px_1'] = Pool(20).map(get_px1, Universe.ticker)
```

But whether a session can be used across threads is not entirely clear, you may have to use something special or fall back to `requests.get`. And the server may not be happy with such a high rate of requests.

Also beware of that `except` as it may silently swallow bugs in your code.

Comment: Thank you! This sped it up slightly, but surprisingly enough for 600 requests it takes at least a minute. Would you suggest removing it from a loop?

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much @Alex Hall !!